# How to create_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler() from AutoscalingV2beta2Api in kubernetes-client in python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am trying to use the [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client) in python in order to create an horizontal pod autoscaler in kubernetes. To do so i make use of the [create_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AutoscalingV2beta2Api.md#create_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler)()  function that belongs to the [AutoscalingV2beta2Api](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/kubernetes).

My code is the following:

```
my_metrics = []
my_metrics.append(client.V2beta2MetricSpec(type='Pods', pods= client.V2beta2PodsMetricSource(metric=client.V2beta2MetricIdentifier(name='cpu'), target=client.V2beta2MetricTarget(average_utilization='50',type='Utilization'))))


body = client.V2beta2HorizontalPodAutoscaler(
    api_version='autoscaling/v2beta2',
    kind='HorizontalPodAutoscaler',
    metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name='php-apache'),
    spec= client.V2beta2HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec(
    max_replicas=10,
    min_replicas=1,
    metrics = my_metrics,
    scale_target_ref = client.V2beta2CrossVersionObjectReference(kind='Object',name='php-apache')
    )) 

v2 = client.AutoscalingV2beta2Api()
ret = v2.create_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler(namespace='default', body=body, pretty=True)
```

And the response i get:

```
HTTP response body: {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "HorizontalPodAutoscaler in version \"v2beta2\" cannot be handled as a HorizontalPodAutoscaler: v2beta2.HorizontalPodAutoscaler.Spec: v2beta2.HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec.Metrics: []v2beta2.MetricSpec: v2beta2.MetricSpec.Pods: v2beta2.PodsMetricSource.Target: v2beta2.MetricTarget.AverageUtilization: readUint32: unexpected character: \ufffd, error found in #10 byte of ...|zation\": \"50\", \"type|..., bigger context ...|\"name\": \"cpu\"}, \"target\": {\"averageUtilization\": \"50\", \"type\": \"Utilization\"}}, \"type\": \"Pods\"}], \"m|...",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "code": 400
}
```

I just want to use the kubernetes-client to call the equivalent of:

```
kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
```

Any working example would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above example permits the creation of a memory based hpa via the latest version of the [k8s python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) (v12.0.1).

```
my_metrics = []
my_metrics.append(client.V2beta2MetricSpec(type='Resource', resource= client.V2beta2ResourceMetricSource(name='memory',target=client.V2beta2MetricTarget(average_utilization= 30,type='Utilization'))))

my_conditions = []
my_conditions.append(client.V2beta2HorizontalPodAutoscalerCondition(status = "True", type = 'AbleToScale'))

status = client.V2beta2HorizontalPodAutoscalerStatus(conditions = my_conditions, current_replicas = 1, desired_replicas = 1)

body = client.V2beta2HorizontalPodAutoscaler(
              api_version='autoscaling/v2beta2',
              kind='HorizontalPodAutoscaler',
              metadata=client.V1ObjectMeta(name=self.app_name),
              spec= client.V2beta2HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec(
                  max_replicas=self.MAX_PODS,
                  min_replicas=self.MIN_PODS,
                  metrics = my_metrics,
                  scale_target_ref = client.V2beta2CrossVersionObjectReference(kind = 'Deployment', name = self.app_name, api_version = 'apps/v1'),
              ),
              status = status)
v2 = client.AutoscalingV2beta2Api()
ret = v2.create_namespaced_horizontal_pod_autoscaler(namespace='default', body=body, pretty=True)
```

Comment: For anybody else who finds this. The difference between the question and this answer is that `status` is included (with a few fields set); adding `status` to the request fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following error:

> ```
> v2beta2.MetricTarget.AverageUtilization: readUint32: unexpected character: \ufffd, error found in #10 byte of ..
> ```

means that its expecting `Uint32` and you are passing a `string`:

```
target=client.V2beta2MetricTarget(average_utilization='50',type='Utilization')
                                           HERE ------^^^^
```

Change it to integer value and it should work.

---

The same information you can find in [python client documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V2beta2MetricTarget.md) (notice the type column).

Comment: you are right about the type of argument, although it does not solve the BadRequest response.